# when ever user exiting from an application the changed language values are again taking their default values in android

Tags: android

I am making a multi language application.
I am having all the language files in the server..
From the server I am directly parsing the values and storing them in static variables in a class.
The problem is when ever I am exiting the application the static values are taking their default values..Can anyone please suggest me..
code for exiting the application:

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have to store them somewhere in your app,static values are gone as soon as you exit the app

Comment: i have used shared prefrences but the values are again taking their default  values

Comment: are you retrieving the values and setting them in your application

Comment: yup..i am retreving and setting the values

Comment: show your code for saving and retrieving values from sharedprefrences

Comment: code for setting values in shared prefrences:

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
        .getSharedPreferences("LanguageSuccess",
          MODE_PRIVATE);
      Editor edt = pref.edit();

      edt.putString("backup",Strings.BACKUP);
      edt.putString("restore",Strings.RESTORE);
      edt.putString("settings",Strings.SETTINGS );
      edt.putString("terms",Strings.TERMS );
      edt.putString("aboutus",Strings.ABOUT);
      edt.putString("contactus",Strings.CONTACT_US);
      edt.putString("exit",Strings.EXIT);
      edt.commit();

Comment: code for retreving :  SharedPreferences pref1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
             "LanguageSuccess", 0);
           
          TextView backup_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_backup);
          Backup= pref1.getString("backup", " ");
           backup_text.setText(Backup);

Comment: instead of LanguageSuccess use your full package name

Comment: k...i wll check and will update you

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the values within the context of your Application. You will have to use Shared Preferences or Database for persistent storage.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3